# Why aren't any of my validations with Zend passing on remote server if they pass locally?

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I have been working on a website and now I'm ready to deploy it. I've put everything on the remote server now and everything seems to be fine, but the problem I'm having is with Zend Validators. In fact I uploaded the whole Zend Framework (28 mb) to the server. I know the path and everything is right because I use Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http to upload files to the server and it does, also checking various validators I added to the file upload. 
However, I can't understand why my character validators are failing, all of them. I tested them locally on localhost and they all work. But in the remote server none of them do. 
Say, for example, I validate a string by doing:

```
$validaUno = new Zend_Validate_Regex('/^([[:alpha:]]|[ÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÄËÏÖÜäëïöü])[[:alpha:]]|[ÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÄËÏÖÜäëïöü]+\s?([[:alpha:]][ÁÉÍÓÚÑñáéíóúÄËÏÖÜäëïöü])?/');
```

against some $_POST variable, and nothing happens, no matter what I write (and the regular expression, which is working locally, should pass for every word followed by a space and then also as many words as you'd like (I've tested this with some script to test regexes).

I also have:

```
$validaTres = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress;
```

and:

```
if(!$validaTres->isValid($correo)) $errors['mail']="No es una direcci&oacute;n de correo electr&oacute;nico v&aacute;lida.";
```

and similarly the other validations that simply do not pass.

I would really appreciate some help cause I'm totally lost here.

By the way, I've read that this must have to do with the script not finding the path to Zend Framework, but what I can't understand is why Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http is working then. If it has to do with the path to the library, what is the correct way to use (**DIR**) or something to get the path correctly. I do the call like this:

```
$libreria='C:/Zend_FW/ZendFramework-1.11.12-minimal/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.$libreria);
require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

then I include this on every page that needs it.
Again I must ask for help, I think this must be very simple, though.

Sorry, I must correct my previous code, it isn't actually what I have on the remote server (I copied the file I have locally), it goes like this:

```
$libreria='Zend/ZendFramework/library';
```

which is what I actually have on the server, a folder called Zend in the root and then the rest of the path. The path is relative to the document, as the script calls it from the same root folder, so I don't see what is wrong. Any suggestions, please? I've tried doing this:

```
../Zend/ZendFramework/libray
```

and

```
./Zend/ZendFramework/library
```

but it just gives me a server error when I tried this. I suppose that is not the correct way to reference a folder in Unix, but I don't really know.

Zend calls its classes exactly the way they are capitalized, I think, precisely to avoid problems with ignoring or not case sensitivity. So the code should work, only it doesn't.

Ok, so I'll reformulate my question: 
What I knew was that having my scripts and their dependencies correctly written (perhaps without being too mindful and prudent about case sensitivity), and the correct folder structure in the server, then the scripts should work.

Then I had questions about the code itself, if the syntax of Zend classes was making sense to reference my input and how the classes are called and their methods are appropiate (if they should be static or another kind, and also if there was a problem in instances of them being made with a call to new operator and so.

I also thought there may have been a problem with the Zend Framework itself in its configuration, namely the way it called its classes and that being related to the operating system as a whole, but there I was truly lost as to which files had to do with that. Fortunately, that was obviously not the problem.

However I was almost certain the problem was not in the code, but, as Seth pointed out, in incompatible syntax between operating systems. The questions I had about using the constant `(__DIR__)` is something I'll put on to investigate later on, because I think sometimes it's easier to configure scripts with this. 
However, in this case I can't figure out how the server is structured so I stuck with my includes.

Anyways, thanks for the help and I must point out that the problem was calling the library with a relative path, as Seth said, and it was as easy as knowing that in Linux/Unix the way to call the root is simply a slash.

### Still having problems, though

Hi all, I don't know what happened, maybe I dreamed about it, but my provider seems to be blocking access to the `set_include_path` function. So I'm still having a lot of problems. I say I dreamed about it because earlier this morning I saw the code working, then it stopped doing so. 
I can see the problem is, over an over again, with the path to the Zend Framework, because if I specify it as a relative path, `$libreria='Zend/ZendFramework/library';` then the weppage simply skips this and acts as if the library weren't loaded. However, if I specify it correctly as an absolute path, the server throws a 500 error.

I've read related posts and tried almost everything, I did `ini_set('include_path', $libreria.":".get_include_path());` and nothing changed. I haven't tried modifying `open_basedir` because I'm pretty sure my provider doesn't allow it. Finally, I've tried including the path directly by entering the full path in the string, and also did getcwd() and chained it to the string, but same behavior is showing.

I also tried moving the folder with the framework to the root of my site (not folder public_html), so that the absolute path `/Zend/ZendFrameWork/library` would be certainly be where I called it. (By root of my site I mean the part of the path that begins the string of my working directory). I even renamed the Zend folder to ZendF to avoid confusion. But I know I'm missing something.

How can this be solved, should I put a fight with my provider?

On second thought, I must say that I really don't think that my provider could be blocking changing the include path, that simply doesn't make sense. I wonder if someone could explain me what directives of the PHP core are usually blocked by some providers, because I suppose without base many things about PHP and security in the servers that I really do not know.

So the problem is still on the way I build the path, and options are but a few: a relative path, or an absolute path.

Comment: I wish to say, I realize I could change my validations to standard php and just do `preg_replace()`, but the thing is that I have built similar validations on another very large project and I don't wish to go through all the code I've already wrote

Comment: So, your local is windows and the remote is unix?  Could it be a capitalization problem?

Comment: @SethBattin I must excuse, I'm not entirely sure the remote is UNIX, at least phpMyAdmin says its connected via UNIX socket, but I don't think that's a proper way of determining it. It has Apache, though, and I think most of the hosting is done in Linux in the company I have the website in. Anyway I'm willing to try your suggestion. ¿What part has to do with capitalizing in the code?

Comment: I mean, if the folders are called exaclty the way I hard code them, then capitalization shouldn't be a problem, but I could just put everything in lowercase, though, for windows, which makes no sense because it makes no difference in windows

Comment: I meant that the path could have an error because of having capitalization wrong in the path definition.  Windows will ignore folder capitalization, unix will not.  I couldn't tell you what exactly is wrong, of course.

Comment: Don't change the folder strings and count on windows to fix them.  I only commented so you could check that possible source of an error.

Comment: @SethBattin is there a precise way to call the root folder in Unix, other than just start without a slash? Also, might there be a problem if I have the Zend Framework in the public_html folder as well. I don't think so, but in windows I don't have it in the same folder.

Comment: I'm thinking I will edit the code in the server, though

Comment: in unix the root folder is `/`.  And I just realized that you were trying to add a relative path to the include path.  I don't think that will work.

Comment: Yes I think I have a problem with my includes, I'm checking what's happening if I change the path with a preceding slash and there's an odd behavior. Now the rest of the page doesn't show, which is strange as I echo the content out of a series of block sentences

Comment: You should really break this question into separate parts.  Comments aren't supposed to contain the answers to questions, they're more for clarification.  And your question truly needs some simplification and clarification.

Comment: @SethBattin Thanks, the thing was that I didn't know I was naming the path relatively in Unix. Adding the slash before solved the problem, I think. The odd behavior I think was because the server had not updated yet the edits I'd made.